# How to setup development environment. .NET Core 2.0 Angular template + Website template downloaded using NPM

Tags: angular, npm, .net-core, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I have started a new project using .NET Core 2.0 with Angular template. My goal is to take an existing HTML template and incorporate it into my project.I chosen free HTML template which I have to install using NPM ([Gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella)). I added a reference to this package in my ***package.json*** [image: pckjson]

Now this template lives inside ***node_modules*** folder:
[image: nodemodules]

What are the next steps I need to take to be able to run my website using this (or any other) template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use Gentelella directly with angular.
You need to translate it to angular2 or use an already translated version.
Please have a look at following links.

- [Angular 2 Components #190](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella/issues/190).
- [kmkatsma/angular2-webpack-starter-gentelella](https://github.com/kmkatsma/angular2-webpack-starter-gentelella)